# Reading from CSV and calculating average (python)

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am really struggling with a programming task I have been handed, I have been asked to read from a CSV file which shows the names of beaches and a rating and then work out the average rating. Any help I could get with this would be great also I[the task given to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6V76.png) am at a beginner level so please don't judge.

Answer (score 2):

For reading CSV files, check out Python's standard library `csv`(https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html)

This content will have enough tutorials and readings that will guide you through your assignment.

As for taking sums and averages, Python's built-in functions(https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html) will do you enough good.

If you are stuck with any of them, feel free to add comments.

Good luck!